# Sorting every 7 rows till end of worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a worksheet with five columns A-E and nearly 10,000 rows. I need to sort every 7 rows till the end of worksheet using data in column C.
The following code does the job for the range A1:E7. Can this code be modified to sort every 7 rows using their relevant data in column C within their range, e.g. C8:C14 for range A8:E14, and C15:C21 for range A15:E21 .. etc. ?

```
Sub sort_7_rows()

Range("A1:E7").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sequencing (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sequencing (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "C1:C7"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sequencing (2)").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:E7")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Any expert assistance with this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty easy way to do this without VBA.  It requires that you create two new columns.  In the first column, just print your row number; so, for example, in row 1, type `1` and in row two, type `2`.  Then select both cells and fill down to the end of your dataset, i.e. 10,000 rows.

In the second column that you created, type the equation `=ROUNDUP(A1/7,0)*7`.  Then fill the equation all the way down to the bottom of the dataset as well.  This will round up each number in the first column to the nearest number divisible by 7.  This essentially groups your data by rows of seven.

Lastly, you'll sort your dataset using the `Sort` window:

[image]

First sort by the values in that second column you created, then by the values in what you called "row C" in your question.

Comment: This is an excellent and practical answer Dazzle, thank you very much. You saved my day :)